# Protractor element(by.css('id_name')).getText() causes browser to wait

Tags: jasmine, protractor, angular6, angular-e2e

#### Version info

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.1.0
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.17
@angular/material                 6.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Protractor: 5.4.0
jasmine-core: 2.6.2
jasmine-spec-reporter: 4.1.0

#### Problem

I wanted to make a simple e2e test to check the inner text of an element after the browser has redirected to a page. However, when checking inside of the element, the browser simply sits on the page for 10 seconds and then gives the following error:

```
1) material App should re-route to login page
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 10 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: htt
ps://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
  While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, #globTitle)

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 14 secs.
[20:04:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[20:04:24] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[20:04:24] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[20:04:24] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
An unexpected error occured: undefined
```

Here is my code:
**HTML**:

```
<div class="main-container">  
    <mat-toolbar [ngStyle]="{'background-color': topBarColor, 'color': 'white'}" class="topbar telative" style = "z-index: 0 !important;">  
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()" *ngIf = "showbtn" value="sidebarclosed">
             <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>  
         </button>  
         <span id = "globTitle">Programme Admin Dashboard</span>  
         <span style = "flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>  
         <button mat-raised-button colour = "warn" *ngIf = "showbtn" (click) = "signOut(); snav.close();" style = "margin-right: 20px;">Sign out</button>  
         <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="No logo available" style = "height: inherit; margin-bottom: 5px;">  
     </mat-toolbar>  
     <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container" [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 0 : 0">  
         <mat-sidenav style = "text-align: center;" #snav id="snav" class="dark-sidebar pl-xs" [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'side' : 'over'" fixedTopGap="0" [opened]= false [disableClose]="mobileQuery.matches" >  
             <app-sidebar (click) = "snav.close()"></app-sidebar>  
         </mat-sidenav>  
         <mat-sidenav-content class="page-wrapper">  
             <div class="page-content">  
                 <router-outlet><app-spinner></app-spinner></router-outlet>  
             </div>  
         </mat-sidenav-content>  
         <ng-template #loadingSpinner>  
         <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>  
             <p>Fetching permissions...</p>  
         </ng-template>  
    </mat-sidenav-container>  
</div>
```

**app.po.ts**:

```
import {browser, by, element, protractor} from 'protractor';  

export class AppPage {  
  navigateTo() {  
    return browser.get('/');  
  }  

  getURIChange(url: string) {  
    const ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  
  browser.wait(ec.urlContains(url), 2000);  
  }  
}
```

**app.e2e-spec.ts**:
(Note that when i remove the last line of code, the test manages to run. In fact, even up to `element(by.css('#globTitle'))` works fine. 
But if i change it to `element(by.css('#globTitle')).getText()`, this is where the browser just waits and i get the error mentioned above.
    import { AppPage } from './app.po';
    import {browser, element, by} from 'protractor';

```
describe('material App', () => {  
  let page: AppPage;  

  beforeEach(() => {  
    page = new AppPage();  
  });  

  it('should re-route to login page', async () => {  
    console.log('Waiting for angular');  
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled();  
  console.log('Angular initialized');  
  console.log('Waiting on navigation to page');  
  // page.navigateTo();  
  await browser.get('http://localhost:4201/');  
  console.log('Navigation completed, should be redirected to the login page');  
  page.getURIChange('/login');  
  expect(element(by.css('#globTitle')).getText()).toEqual('Programme Admin Dashboard');  
  });  
});
```

Also, i'm not sure if this would help, but here are my protractor configuration and karma configurations just in case.
**protractor.conf.js**:
    const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

```
exports.config = {  
  allScriptsTimeout: 10000,  
  specs: [  
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'  
  ],  
  capabilities: {  
    'browserName': 'chrome'  
  },  
  directConnect: true,  
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',  
  framework: 'jasmine',  
  jasmineNodeOpts: {  
    showColors: true,  
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000,  
  print: function() {}  
  },  
  onPrepare() {  
    require('ts-node').register({  
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'  
  });  
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));  
  }  
};
```

**karma.conf.js**:

```
module.exports = function (config) {  
  config.set({  
    basePath: '',  
  frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],  
  plugins: [  
      require('karma-jasmine'),  
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),  
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),  
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),  
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')  
    ],  
  client:{  
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser  
  },  
  coverageIstanbulReporter: {  
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],  
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true  
  },  
  angularCli: {  
      environment: 'dev'  
  },  
  reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],  
  port: 9876,  
  colors: true,  
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,  
  autoWatch: true,  
  browsers: ['Chrome'],  
  customLaunchers: {  
      ChromeNoSandbox: {  
        base: 'Chrome',  
  flags: ['--no-sandbox']  
      }  
    },  
  singleRun: false,  
  });  
};
```

Comment: are you wedded to waiting for angular? It seems like await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); could fix this if you can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you are not returning the callback in your step definitions.

So jasmine thinks you are doing or waiting for some actions to happen.But once timeout occured that is 10 seconds it throws an error

```
it('should re-route to login page', async (done) => { 
  console.log('Waiting for angular'); 
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(); 
  console.log('Angular initialized'); 
  console.log('Waiting on navigation to page'); // page.navigateTo(); 
  await browser.get('http://localhost:4201/'); 
  console.log('Navigation completed, should be redirected to the login page'); 
  page.getURIChange('/login'); 
 Var a = element(by.css('#globTitle');
  Var b = a.getText().then((value)=>{console.log('title is'+value);
return value;}) 

expect(b).toEqual('Programme Admin Dashboard'); done() 
    });
```

Comment: Step definitions? Did you mean inside of the it block of code? 
Also, i have tried 

    element(by.css('#globTitle')).getText().then((text) => {
        expect(text).toBe('Programme Admin Dashboard'); 
    });

This also did not work

Comment: Add done like i have added in the answer. if required increase your global timeout

Comment: I have increased my global timeout to 100000ms and still the error persists. I realized that the problem seems to happen with almost all functions that return a promise. browser.getTitle() gives me the same behaviour. I have tried a catch statement as well with no luck. None of the promises are resolving

Comment: Please check if its printing the title in console.log

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const el1 =  await $('#globTitle').getText();
expect(el1).toEqual('Programme Admin Dashboard');
```

getText() waits for a promise to resolve and hence doesn't work the way it was before.

Comment: After adding `import * as $ from 'jquery';` at the top and adding the line you suggested, i received the following error:
(node:11188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jQuery requires a window with a document...
Additionally, the code i had was straight from the docs and still not working for me, though it was working for other people

Comment: Did you try print el1 ? Wat does it say ?

Comment: It was not letting me print since the jQuery error prevented the typescript from being compiled